# declara una dependencia de la configuración 'compilar' a la configuración 'default' que no se declara en el descriptor para el proyecto:

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, android-asynctask, android-viewpager, webview-android

Deseo utilizar en el MainActivity clases que se encuentran dentro de un directorio.

Sin embargo al agregarlo pROJECT sTRUCTURE/ Dependencias/ Modulo dependencias me ocurre el error mencionado. Alguien me sabe que estoy haciendo mal?

este es mi settings.gradle

```
include ':app'
include ':LibrarySaiolib:wrapper'
```

Comment: Hola Dennis, "Deseo utilizar en el MainActivity clases que se encuentran dentro de un directorio." dentro de un directorio del mismo proyecto? porque no agregas una imagen de la estructura para ser más especifico.